# Auto save grid in extjs

Tags: php, extjs

I want to auto save the contents of a grid in extjs editor grid. Can anybody please help? At present my row is getting saved when the insert key is pressed, but I want to save it as soon as a new row is focused.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the events in the  [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/).

```
grid.on('validateedit', function(e) {
  var rec = e.record;
  //some code to save the record.
});
```

If this event doesn't suit there may be an alternative event in the  [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) to match your needs.